# How to manage auto sequencing of values in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to starting incrementing from a certain sequence number by 1. externalId is of the format "EXT20000", its a unique number and is getting incremented by 1 and we are migrating from an external system to Elasticsearch and the count increment has to be managed. I don't want to increment this from within the application as multiple containers could be running and having it increase atomically is difficult. How to increment in Elasticsearch, whenever **before** a new document is inserted. I want to ask ES for this sequence number and save it along with the document in the format of "EXT" + "next-sequence-number".

```
@Document(indexName = "bars", shards = 1, versionType = VersionType.INTERNAL, createIndex = true)
public class Bar implements Persistable<String> {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String externalId;
...
}
```

Comment: Check out the caveats here first: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-create-autoincrement-id-in-es-using-java-api-in-storm/28832/2

Comment: I am not referring to the primary key at all, need something unique being generated for the field

Comment: Gotcha. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1):

What I know is that guaranteeing atomicity across the cluster is impossible. What's worse, you don't have access to other docs when indexing documents so [ingest pipelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/accessing-data-in-pipelines.html#accessing-data-in-pipelines) are out of the question too (at least if we're talking incrementation in one go.)

Why is atomic incrementation a requirement? [Here](https://medium.com/@Mareks_082/auto-increment-keys-vs-uuid-a74d81f7476a) and [here](https://www.clever-cloud.com/blog/engineering/2015/05/20/why-auto-increment-is-a-terrible-idea/) are some classic reasons why not to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately its a requirement from an external system, so have to support it somehow.